# Why is Twitter's 1000-follows-per-day limit ignored for some accounts, but not for others?

Tags: social-network, twitter

Something strange is happening to different accounts I manage. Some accounts have the regular following limit of 1000 follows per day. But others let me follow up to 3000 follows per day sometimes. I can't find information about Twitter following limit which explains this. I believe Twitter still states it's 1000 per day for any account.

Why is this 1000-follows-per-day limit ignored/raised for some accounts, but not for others?

Comment: Are you asking why a site would implement a throttling function, or are you asking why you are seeing this behavior on Twitter?

Comment: None of those. I'm asking why they state they have a 1,000 follow per day limit, and then this limit is skipped in some accounts and not in others without explanation in its documentation.

Comment: This seems to fall under the "things not to ask about" per the [on-topic help page](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "Don't ask about: anything not directly related to building, administering, managing and cultivating communities. **If yours is a digital community, please avoid asking questions about a technical feature of your platform.**"

Answer (score 1):

Twitter states:

> Twitter's technical follow limits: Every account can follow 5,000 users total. Once you've followed 5,000 users, there are limits to the number of additional users you can follow. This number is different for each account and is based on your ratio of followers to following; this ratio is not published.

I'm looking at the phrase *"This number is different for each account"* which seems to answer your question.

Both this and the daily follow limit are likely set to prevent abuse of Twitter. Those numbers would need to be adjusted over time to prevent abuse of Twitter.

Behavior outside the norms in a global scale social media like attempting to follow every account would quickly make Twitter undesirable for the targets of such campaigns. To prevent that level of abuse limits would be enacted. For accounts that have legitimately grown and for which people show interest the limits are likely raised to allow the famous or topical to avoid those limits. Sorting out who is an abuser and who is famous or topical is going to change over time, but as indicated above one of the things that they are looking at is the ratio between followers and following.

Comment: you are talking about the limit in general, not the limit per day. They are different limits. There is a limit in general of 5,000 users, and a limit per day of 1,000 per day. That limit you quote makes reference to the limit in general, my question is about the limit per day that is another limit.